Very weird network issues in my local network and/or internet connection
I'm experiencing weird behavior in my local network and/or internet connection.
It seems that some requests fail for unknown reasons. I'm experiencing this with different devices in my network, but the issues are gone if I connect to another network.
The symptoms are the following:

GraphQl requests are failing sometimes to certain servers, e.g.

curl 'https://graphql.datocms.com/' \
    -H 'Authorization: 12345' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -H 'Accept: application/json' \
    --data-binary '{ "query": "query { allPosts { title } }" }'

curl: (35) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

If I try this multiple times, about 50% of the requests fail. If I do the query from a node application, it sometimes fails with this:
➜ node query.js
node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12502
      Error.captureStackTrace(err, this);
            ^

TypeError: fetch failed
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12502:13
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  [cause]: Error: read ECONNRESET
      at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:218:20) {
    errno: -54,
    code: 'ECONNRESET',
    syscall: 'read'
  }
}

For other servers it seems to always work, e.g:
curl --location 'https://swapi-graphql.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/index' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{"query":"{\r\n  allFilms {\r\n    films {\r\n      title\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}","variables":{}}'

{"data":{"allFilms":{"films":[{"title":"A New Hope"},{"title":"The Empire Strikes Back"},{"title":"Return of the Jedi"},{"title":"The Phantom Menace"},{"title":"Attack of the Clones"},{"title":"Revenge of the Sith"}]}}}


Other tools that download something, sometimes fail

If I try it again, it would work at some point

Some requests on websites sometimes fail

Again, this only happens sometimes.


What I've tried so far:

Restart Router, restart Laptop, reset Router to factory settings. No effect.
Try with different devices (2 Macbooks, Windows Laptop) in the same network. Same behavior.
Try with cable instead of wifi. No effect.
Connect to other intnet source, e.g. to shared LTE-hotspot from my phone. Issue gone!
Look for suspicious settings in the router interface, didn't find anything, but also wasn't sure what to look for.
Speed-test, e.g. on https://www.speedtest.net/de. Looks all good.
ping google.com. This looks like this:

➜  exp ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.16.174): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.16.174: icmp_seq=0 ttl=116 time=11.254 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.16.174: icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=11.364 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.16.174: icmp_seq=2 ttl=116 time=12.189 ms

After about ~50 calls, sometimes I get a Request timeout for icmp_seq 75
I think the issues just started today at some point, during the last weeks everything was working as expected, as far as I can tell. So it might just be an issues with my provider? (o2 in Germany)
I really hope you can help me or point me into a direction on how to approach this issue. Thank you so much!

to perform diagnostics you must be cabled only. don't use wifi. When cabled with wifi switched off, do you still experience ping failure? What router doe you have?

Also, what kind of internet connection do you have? VDSL/CABLE/FIBRE?

Try to connect your laptop directly to your modem by cable and do the tests again. If problems are gone, consider replacing your wireless router. If the same problems exist, contact your Internet service provider.
